# To find the Percentage Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table and the structure of it is as follows:

```
VoteId  QuestionId  AnswerId    EmployeeId

6        1              5              2
7        1              1              1
10       2              6              1
12       1              1             24
```

Here for QuestionId 1, we have 2 answers. AnswerId 1 and 5. For Answer 1 two employees have voted, EmployeeId 1 and 24. Also for AnswerId 5 EmployeeId 2 has voted.

Now from this table I need to calculate the percentage for each `AnswerId` for individual `QuestionId` according to  `EmployeeId`.

How could I solve this?

Comment: You need to elaborate a litle more, how is the percentage calculated based on all of the other fields?

Comment: to querstionid? what has the employee to do with it

Comment: @Ramdas so for voteid = 6, the percentage is 0.25 (0-1) because only exists one answer with id=5 and there are 4 anwsers in total?

Comment: Please anyone help me to solve this issue

Comment: You've been offered two possible solutions, and there's no feedback from you on them (i.e. you haven't commented if they are helpful or not, what issues there are etc.). Maybe that's why there's no more suggestions: maybe people visiting your question see the answers, see no feedback from you, and perhaps think twice before posting anything.

Comment: Dear Andriy, you made some edit in my question. Actually this is what I need. But the solutions I got is not meet my requirements.

Comment: Dear Andriy, can you help me to solve this. Please.

Comment: Actually this is a table represents voting for answers by employee for each questions. So i need voting percentage of answers for every questions(for each questionId seperately) voted by employees.

Comment: Dear Andriy, I think my data is not enough for you to understand.That's why I'm not getting required answer. Sorry Andriy its because of my mistake..

Comment: I'm sorry about my not replying you! I just wasn't aware about your responses. In the future, if you want to make sure a person gets your message addressed at him/her, please make sure to include their name **preceded by `@`**, like e.g. "@AndriyM" (without quotation marks), somewhere in the body of the message. That way the person will be automatically notified by this site's messaging system. Read more about it in this FAQ section: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were after:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (VoteId  INT,QuestionId  INT,AnswerId    INT,EmployeeId INT)
INSERT @t VALUES 
(6,   1,    5,   2),
(7,   1,    1,    1),
(10,  2,    6,    1),
(12,  1,    1,   24)

SELECT  QuestionId, 
        COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t)
        AS PercentageOfVotesReceived
FROM    @t
GROUP   BY QuestionId

SELECT  AnswerId, 
        COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t)
        AS PercentageOfVotesReceived
FROM    @t
GROUP   BY AnswerId 

SELECT  EmployeeId, 
        COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t)
        AS PercentageOfVotesReceived
FROM    @t
GROUP   BY EmployeeId
```